# Как посмотреть историю записей в PL/SQL Developer 15?

Tags: plsql-developer

**НЕ историю моих запросов**
Нужно увидеть как менялись записи в таблице и от какого пользователя. Оракл документация ведет на "History Tab" но в PL/SQL Developer 15 такого нету. Другого софта нету и установить невозможно и плагины для PL/SQL Developer 15 установить тоже невозможно